# How to create a mesh object in ITK using Python bindings?

Tags: python, itk

I am trying to create a Mesh object in Python. I am using the python bindings which are being installed from the following [web page](http://www.paulnovo.org/repository). As far as the c++ code is concerned we can do it as follows

```
      MeshType::Pointer mesh = MeshType::New();
```

I am very new to use even ITK. Have no idea how to create it. In the constructor of Mesh in the c++ documentation, it says one necessary argument which is the TPixelType. Unable to locate that as well.

Could anybody help me please with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you I would take a look at the Python bindings that come with ITK 4.0.  You can get access to them by turning on the option WRAP_ITK_PYTHON in cmake.

Once, you compile ITK with the python bindings turned on you can create 2 mesh types out of the box:

```
import itk
meshType2D = itk.Mesh.D2Q.New()
meshType3D = itk.Mesh.D3Q.New()
```

alternatively you can explicitly instantiate your classes as follows:

```
import itk
meshType2D = itk.Mesh[itk.D, 2, itk.QuadEdgeMeshTraits.D2BBFF]
meshType3D = itk.Mesh[itk.D, 3, itk.QuadEdgeMeshTraits.D3BBFF]
```

This will give you 2 and 3 dimensional meshes of double type pixel values with default mesh traits.  As far as pixel types in ITK go, these amount to the basic C++ variables types: double, float, unsigned int, etc.  These basic types are wrapped in python and can be found in the ITK namespace:  itk.D, itk.F, itk.UI, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have ITK 3,14. It works for me with `itk.Mesh.D2D.New()` but not with `itk.Mesh.D2D.New()`. As far as the explicit creation of the mesh if i give for example `itk.Mesh[itk.F,3]` it gives the following error. `itkTemplate : No template (<itkCType double>, 3) for the itk::Mesh class`. Can you please tell me the easiest way to explore python bindings for the ITk. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also at website the latest official release is 3.2. I could not locate ITK 4.0. Thanks

Comment: Hey Shan,

There is only a limited subset of all the possible dimensions and pixel types already wrapped in python for all the different ITK template types such as Mesh and Image.  For the case of a Mesh I think it might only be double wrapped out of the box.  That's why your call to itk.Mesh[itk.F,3] fails.

To get ITK v 4.x over 3.x you need to go to the git repository.  You can find it by searching ITK on github or through the links on the ITK website.

Comment: Thanks horseBananaz, I tried it already... I cloned the git repository... But I am unable to build it.... I t will be very nice of you if you could please recommend me to any good webpage with a detailed explanation f the building and the installation process.